# How to NOT show Undefined when not assign value

Tags: javascript

I have this function in JavaScript

```
function person(settings) {
  console.log(settings.name);
  console.log(settings.age);
}
```

And I assigned value to the function :

```
function({
  name: `Nana`,
});
```

The result are

```
Nana
Undefined
```

I just want to skip to assign value to `age` and also I don't want to get `undefined`  I want to get the result only `Nana`

What should I do?

Comment: Put an if-statement around it that checks if the value is not `undefined`?

Answer (score 2):

Your function print both, so you see the undefined one. You can use if statement to print only if it is not undefined.

```
function person(settings) {
   if (settings.name != undefined) console.log(settings.name); 
   if (settings.age != undefined) console.log(settings.age);
}
```

also you can use:

```
function person(settings) {
   if (settings.name) console.log(settings.name); 
   if (settings.age) console.log(settings.age);
}
```

this work because any javascript value can be convert to a boolean value, and the folowing values convert to 'false':

```
undefined
null
0
-0
NaN
""  // the empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
function person(settings) {
 result = '';
   if(settings.name!=undefined) {
    result += settings.name;
    }
    result += ' ';
   if(settings.age!=undefined) {
        result+=settings.age;
    }

    
    alert(result);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p onclick="person({
  name: `Nana`
});">Click Here</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[how to and test video](https://youtu.be/-y1i91AwW-8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat way of implementing paranoid / fallback values using `||`.

```js
function person(settings) {
  console.log(settings.name || '');
  console.log(settings.age || '');
}
```

Above will give you a fallback value of `''` (empty string)

If you do not want to trigger `console.log` at all, a simple `if` statement or `&&` will do it for you.

```js
  settings.name && console.log(settings.name);
  settings.age && console.log(settings.age);

  // OR

  if (settings.name) console.log(settings.name);
  if (settings.age) console.log(settings.age);
```